# Is it possible to edit search results from within a display template (using data from an executeQueryAsync request)?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, display-template

Does anyone know how to modify search results before they are rendered when the modification depends on data returned from an async request?

I have a requirement to filter some search results according to only show results from sites that the user is following.

So far I have done this by calling some JavaScript from my display template which iterates through the page of results and removes whichever are not amongst the users followed sites (which I have retrieved with the SocialFollowingManager).

This approach works but it does cause some problems around the results count and paging and I would much prefer to remove the unwanted result rows from the result set before they are rendered to the page.

I can do this by modifying the results in ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows but unfortunately by the time I have retrieved the data I need to do the filtering the page has loaded and the results have rendered.

Is there a way I can hold the rendering of the display template back while I wait for the async request to complete?

I tried using OnPreRender but even though the process was kicked off before the render began it still didn't work because the page loaded before the async call returned. I also tried requesting the data with a non-async call (just ExecuteQuery) but it seems that this isn't possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147472/cant-get-clientcontext-exicutequery-to-work-in-javascript).

Or is there just a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or SharePoint on premises?

Comment: I'm on premises.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `OnPreRender` handler. Here is a pseudo code you can try with

```
ctx.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler;

function preRenderHandler(ctx) {
    //Get the Page's user is following here

    //Remove the result here by accessing 
    ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows
}
```

While retrieving `Followed` pages data you should hold back the call by making it `Synchronous` using `jQuery` `promises`

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: I'm not clear what you are suggesting Amal. I've tried using OnPreRender but it doesn't alter the fact that the CSOM api to retrieve social data only takes asyncronous calls. I don't see how using a promise rather than a callback would change this.

Comment: @Tim I am suggesting to block the PreRender call till the SocailData is retrieved.